# Importing Excel spreadsheet into sql as a table error

Tags: sql, excel, datetime, import

I am trying to import an excel spreadsheet into a new table in SQL, but when I try to do the aforementioned, I get an error I believe it is a datetime format error but I have tried changing it and still get it can anyone help below is the table.

> `Copying to 'Drawings and Documents register$' (Error)
>
> Messages
>   Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x00040EDA.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "Destination Input" (70)" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "input "Destination Input" (70)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - 'Drawings and Documents register$'" (59) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (70). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - 'Drawings and Documents register$'" (1) returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Answer (score 0):

It can be a number of things that went wrong, have your tried your import on a single row that has validated data ?

You could be trying to insert a string into a integer column or a Null-value into a column that does not allow Nulls...